# Django: How to create child objects based on submitted json data

Tags: django, json, django-forms, django-views

I am working with a payment system. Upon button click, I submit a payment to an external rest api (Stripe) and upon success it returns a javascript object called "token". I store the "token" object in a hidden html field and then submit my form using jquery. After that, I am using CreateView to save the PaymentForm (which is based on the Payment model listed below). The Payment model has a ForeignKey field to a child StripeToken model

My question is, at which point in the view or form do I parse the json string and create the StripeToken object that will be associated to the Payment object?

I am unsure if this is a case for formsets because the nested data is acquired from an external source (Stripe rest api), not a nested form.

my models:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    amount = CurrencyField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    stripe_token = models.ForeignKey('StripeToken')

class StripeToken(models.Model):
    token_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    token_object = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    used = models.BooleanField()
    livemode = models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this through the form's `__init__` method. "stripe_data" is the name of the hidden field containing the json string. As show below, I first check if stripe_data is in self.data. Next, I parse the string using json.loads. Afterwards I create the necessary StripeToken object and assign it accordingly.

This works for me. If there is a more appropriate way to do this then I am eager to learn how.

```
import json

class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'stripe_data' in self.data:
            stripe_data = json.loads(self.data.get('stripe_data', None))
            token = stripe_data['token']

            stripe_token = StripeToken()
            stripe_token.token_id = token.get('id', None)
            stripe_token.token_object = token.get('object', None)
            stripe_token.type = token.get('type', None)
            stripe_token.used = token.get('used', None)
            stripe_token.livemode = token.get('livemode', None)
            stripe_token.created = token.get('created', None)
            stripe_token.save()

            self.data['stripe_token'] = stripe_token.id
```

---

**UPDATE**

The above is not the best approach. Instead it is best to add a non-model field to the form for the stripe data

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stripe_data = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

And then move what was described above in the form's `__init__` into the form's `clean()` method.